# RecyclerView ItemDecoration for vertrical list

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using this implementation for ItemDecoration:
https://gist.github.com/zokipirlo/82336d89249e05bba5aa

This is my resource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="line">
        <stroke
            android:color="@color/music_player_divider"
            android:width="1dp"/>

        <size android:height="1dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

And i dont see any divider. If is set `<size android:height="2dp"/>` I do get a line. problem is, this line has a bottom and top padding. All i want is 2px width line with no paddings.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke
                android:color="@color/color_accent"
                android:width="1dp"/>

            <size android:height="1dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Works fine for me. You are appending  at the end right?

Comment: What do you mean "appending at the end"?

Comment: As in you don't have </layer-list> at the end of your code example. Is it missing from your project too?